# Seeking documentation for SpatiaLite functions like AddGeometryColumn

Tags: spatialite, documentation

I'm looking for the documentation for SpatiaLite functions but all my links are failing.

The Gaia GIS website appears to be down https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/gaia-gis.it.html, but I'm not sure if this is a temporary problem, or whether the docs have been moved somewhere else.

I have found some docs on the Wayback Machine, but this also suggests that some pages, at least, are no longer maintained. http://web.archive.org/web/20200503035740/http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/new-geom.html

Is there a current repository for the SpatiaLite Manual and documentation?

Comment: Check [SpatiaLite 4.0.0 SQL functions reference list](http://priede.bf.lu.lv/ftp/pub/DatuBazes/SQLite/spatialite/spatialite-sql-4.0.0.html) / [AddGeometryColumn](http://priede.bf.lu.lv/ftp/pub/DatuBazes/SQLite/spatialite/spatialite-sql-4.0.0.html#p16)

Comment: Thanks for the link @KadirŞahbaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatialite functions as they appear in the latest released SpatiaLite version are documented in http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

The site is indeed down at the moment. It was alive yesterday.

**Update**

The site is now back again (2020-12-07 06:30 UTC).